# Cannot get the correct calculation when using a Smart Match Operator

Tags: perl, hash, match, subroutine

I've just been completing an assignment - I asked a question about this last week and was advised not to use a Smart Match Operator, but I have a greater grasp of it over Hashes.

Basically this subroutine is one of 4 subroutines. It Opens a file containing 125,000 mammals, loads it into a list, loops over the list and splits it into scalars. Loads parts of the split list into a calculator which returns a value ($Calcdist).

What I want this to do it basically count the number of species in the area which is does do. somewhat. 
The data I'm using at the moment is:

```
$File =("Mammal.txt");
$Distance = 5.0;
$Lat = 51.75;
$Long = -1.25;
```

With this information it tells me there are 95 animals in that area (using another subroutine) This subroutine should tell me that there are 30 unique species but instead it prints the number 9.

Where abouts am I going wrong? Is my 'if' and 'else' incorrect? I know there are much better ways of coding perl but this is just the way I have been taught.

```
sub BiodiversityCount ($$$$)
     {
          my ($Filename, $Distance, $Lat1, $Lon1) = @_;
          my ($Line, $Index, $CalcDist, $Counter, $Counter2, $Index2);
          my (@List, @Part, @Species);
          open (INF, "<", $Filename) or die ("Cannot open Mammal.txt\n");
          @List = <INF>;
          close (INF);
          for ($Index=0;$Index<@List;$Index++)
               {
                   @Part = split ("\t", $List[$Index]);
                   $CalcDist = CalculateDistance ($Lat1, $Lon1, $Part[1], $Part[2]);
                   if ($CalcDist<$Distance)
                       {                    
                           if ($Part[0] ~~ @Species)
                               {
                               $Counter++
                               }
                           else
                               {
                               @Species = $Part[0]; 
                               }                                    
                       }
              }
          #printf @Species;
          print("The number of unique species found upto $Distance km from $Lat1, $Lon1 is: $Counter\n");
          #Number of Unique species found in an area
          #Smart match operator
          #Hashes - declared using my %___
      }
BiodiversityCount ($File, $Distance, $Lat, $Long);
```

Test data:

```
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Apodemus flavicollis
Mustela erminea
Lepus europaeus
Apodemus sylvaticus
Sciurus carolinensis
Talpa europaea
Arvicola amphibius
Rhinolophus ferrumequinum
Arvicola amphibius
Muntiacus reevesi
Apodemus sylvaticus
Sciurus carolinensis
Sciurus carolinensis
Sorex araneus
Erinaceus europaeus
Sciurus vulgaris
Vulpes vulpes
Clethrionomys glareolus
Sorex araneus
Meles meles
Arvicola amphibius
Microtus agrestis
Vulpes vulpes
Nyctalus noctula
Erinaceus europaeus
Neomys fodiens
Meles meles
Erinaceus europaeus
Capreolus capreolus
Pipistrellus pipistrellus sensu lato
Micromys minutus
Rattus norvegicus
Sorex minutus
Plecotus
Erinaceus europaeus
Muntiacus reevesi
Vulpes vulpes
Mustela erminea
Oryctolagus cuniculus
Dama dama
Erinaceus europaeus
Talpa europaea
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Sciurus carolinensis
Vulpes vulpes
Sorex minutus
Talpa europaea
Talpa europaea
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Mustela vison
lethrionomys glareolus
Microtus agrestis
Sciurus vulgaris
Mustela nivalis
Apodemus sylvaticus
Meles meles
Meles meles
Vulpes vulpes
Capreolus capreolus
Mustela nivalis
Mustela putorius
Microtus agrestis
Sorex araneus
Sorex minutus
Muscardinus avellanarius
Muntiacus reevesi
Sciurus carolinensis
Dama dama
Muntiacus reevesi
Talpa europaea
Muntiacus reevesi
Microtus agrestis
Dama dama
Microtus agrestis
Talpa europaea
Arvicola amphibius
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Sorex minutus
Vulpes vulpes
Dama dama
Talpa europaea
Apodemus sylvaticus
Sorex araneus
Microtus agrestis
Lepus europaeus
Sorex minutus
Neomys fodiens
Vulpes vulpes
```

Comment: Just to let you know, the smartmatch operator has some serious issues and has now been marked [experimental](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental) and may go away in the future. This isn't the problem you're having, but it's a warning about depending upon the use of smartmatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want a hash to count unique species. I made an adjustment to your code which uses a hash, `%species_count`. There are other changes you might make, but for now, I think this hash will get you what you want. (I also fudged $CalcDist = 1;#CalculateDistance ($Lat1, $Lon1, $Part[1], $Part[2]); to run the script, just change it back to what it was originally)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $File =("Mammal.txt");
my $Distance = 5.0;
my $Lat = 51.75;
my $Long = -1.25;

sub BiodiversityCount ($$$$)
     {
          my ($Filename, $Distance, $Lat1, $Lon1) = @_;
          my ($Line, $Index, $CalcDist, $Counter, $Counter2, $Index2);
          my (@List, @Part, %species_count);
          #open (INF, "<", $Filename) or die ("Cannot open Mammal.txt\n");
          chomp(@List = <DATA>);
          #close (INF);
          for ($Index=0;$Index<@List;$Index++)
               {
                   @Part = split ("\t", $List[$Index]);
                   $CalcDist = 1;#CalculateDistance ($Lat1, $Lon1, $Part[1], $Part[2]);
                   if ($CalcDist<$Distance)
                       {
                           $species_count{$Part[0]}++;
                       }
              }
          #printf @Species;
          #print("The number of unique species found upto $Distance km from $Lat1, $Lon1 is: $Counter\n");
          print("The number of unique species found upto $Distance km from $Lat1, $Lon1 is: ",  scalar keys %species_count, "\n");
          #Number of Unique species found in an area
          #Smart match operator
          #Hashes - declared using my %___
      }
BiodiversityCount ($File, $Distance, $Lat, $Long);

__DATA__
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Apodemus flavicollis
Mustela erminea
Lepus europaeus
Apodemus sylvaticus
Sciurus carolinensis
Talpa europaea
Arvicola amphibius
Rhinolophus ferrumequinum
Arvicola amphibius
Muntiacus reevesi
Apodemus sylvaticus
Sciurus carolinensis
Sciurus carolinensis
Sorex araneus
Erinaceus europaeus
Sciurus vulgaris
Vulpes vulpes
Clethrionomys glareolus
Sorex araneus
Meles meles
Arvicola amphibius
Microtus agrestis
Vulpes vulpes
Nyctalus noctula
Erinaceus europaeus
Neomys fodiens
Meles meles
Erinaceus europaeus
Capreolus capreolus
Pipistrellus pipistrellus sensu lato
Micromys minutus
Rattus norvegicus
Sorex minutus
Plecotus
Erinaceus europaeus
Muntiacus reevesi
Vulpes vulpes
Mustela erminea
Oryctolagus cuniculus
Dama dama
Erinaceus europaeus
Talpa europaea
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Sciurus carolinensis
Vulpes vulpes
Sorex minutus
Talpa europaea
Talpa europaea
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Mustela vison
lethrionomys glareolus
Microtus agrestis
Sciurus vulgaris
Mustela nivalis
Apodemus sylvaticus
Meles meles
Meles meles
Vulpes vulpes
Capreolus capreolus
Mustela nivalis
Mustela putorius
Microtus agrestis
Sorex araneus
Sorex minutus
Muscardinus avellanarius
Muntiacus reevesi
Sciurus carolinensis
Dama dama
Muntiacus reevesi
Talpa europaea
Muntiacus reevesi
Microtus agrestis
Dama dama
Microtus agrestis
Talpa europaea
Arvicola amphibius
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Muntiacus reevesi
Sorex minutus
Vulpes vulpes
Dama dama
Talpa europaea
Apodemus sylvaticus
Sorex araneus
Microtus agrestis
Lepus europaeus
Sorex minutus
Neomys fodiens
Vulpes vulpes
```

Comment: Hey thank you! This solution is great! I was wondering though, is there a simpler way to calculate how many values are in the hash? I didn't like the scalar keys being in the print so I used 

$Counter = scalar keys $species_count{$Part[0]};

Instead which gave me a value which was correct. Is there any other way to do this? 
Also how does this hash work? I'm thinking its similar to a list where it can become interchangeable between a hash and a scalar. Is the "$species_count{$Part[0]}" used to put values into the hash and the %species_count contains them all?

Comment: @Arkturaz This hash contains the number of times each species occurs (a value that is of no use in your circumstance). *so I used $Counter = scalar keys $species_count{$Part[0]}; Instead which gave me a value which was correct* is not correct s/b *$Counter = scalar keys $species_count;* To better understand about hashes you might try **[this link](https://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AkQnd1iBD8rBCs1Wvevr6bSbvZx4?fr=yfp-t-328-s&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&p=perl%20hash%20example)** and read about them.

Comment: @Arkturaz Also, to see how your hash is constructed, you could add `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%species_count` after your `for` loop. That will show your hash keys and the number of times each key occurred in your data (the hash values, which I said you don't use in this script).

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
@Species = $Part[0];
```

Should be:

```
push @Species, $Part[0];
```

Also, you probably want to be `chomp`ing the lines you read from the file to remove the trailing line break characters.

You also have at least one logic error: I think you ought to be `++`ing the counter only when `not $Part[0] ~~ @Species`.

Comment: Hi, I managed to get it to work by using a basic calculation alongside that.
It gave me a value of 65 which I took away from the 95 to give me 30- This seemed too good to be true so I tried it agaisnt other test data, and it gave me the correct answer somehow, not sure how hahah!

I'm just wondering, what does the push function do? There's not sense submitting a piece of work if I don't understand every bit of it.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `push` adds an item to the end of an array. (`unshift` is the corresponding keyword to add to the beginning of the array. `shift` and `pop` remove an item from the beginning and end respectively.) Your original line wasn't *adding* to the end of the array, but *replacing* the contents of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to use the `~~` operator (incorrectly) to perform a set-membership test.

Smartmatch has been re-declared as experimental, so you may wish to avoid it. You can avoid it and at the same time make your code clearer in intent, and actually work, by rewriting it. For example you could use the `any` function from `List::Util`:

```
if ($Part[0] ~~ @Species)
```

now becomes

```
if ( any { $Part[0] eq $_ } @Species )
```

In general you should avoid smartmatch for now, unless and until core perl decides on a better set of semantics for it, and declares it non-experimental again.

Comment: Problem is, I've been told to use either a Hash or Smart Match Operator. And I'm not allowed to use anything else to solve this subroutine.